# SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 Upgrade or Migrate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, migrate, migration, upgrade-sharepoint

I am in the process of upgrading SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016.  What I've done so far is attach the SharePoint 2010 db into Sharepoint 2013 environment, completed the mount and upgrade.  However, it looks horrible in SharePoint 2013.  The company template, web parts are broken, etc.  What are the benefits of upgrading vs. migrating?  Is it better to redesign/build the site in SharePoint 2016 and use a third party tool to migrate the data?  I haven't looked at the workflows yet.  Can Workflows and MySites be migrated or is that an upgrade?

Any recommendations, tips, best practices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the 2013 database attach is to upgrade all sites using `Upgrade-SPSite` as well as convert to claims using `Convert-SPWebApplication`. Yes, all master page and other features will break as part of this migration. Many of your 2010 site customizations cannot be carried forward regardless of how you migrate.

MySites can be upgraded or migrated. Workflows are problematic as you cannot carry forward the workflow history and you would need to terminate workflows prior to a migration upgrade.